# fetch api - itunes search api error

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to use the iTunes search API and the fetch api.

When I try the following I get a response the in the console.

```
  fetch('https://api.github.com/users/bootstrap').then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(j) {
    console.log(j);
  });
```

However when I try

```
  fetch('https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson',{mode: 'no-cors'}).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(a) {
    console.log(a);
  });
```

I get an error `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input(…)`

Is it possible to grab the iTunes API data in this way?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an opaque request, and what it serves for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292537/what-is-an-opaque-request-and-what-it-serves-for)

Answer (score 0):

From MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode):

> no-cors — Prevents the method from being anything other than HEAD, GET
>   or POST. If any ServiceWorkers intercept these requests, they may not
>   add or override any headers except for these. In addition, **JavaScript**
>   **may not access any properties of the resulting Response**. This ensures
>   that ServiceWorkers do not affect the semantics of the Web and
>   prevents security and privacy issues arising from leaking data across
>   domains.

That's why you get empty response in JS and the JSON error when parsing the empty string `JSON.parse("")`.