# What limitations apply to opaque responses?

Tags: javascript, cors, service-worker, fetch-api

[Opaque responses](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-opaque) are defined as part of the [Fetch API](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/), and represent the result of a request made to a remote origin when [CORS](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol) is not enabled.

What practical limitations and "gotchas" exist around how opaque responses can be used, both from JavaScript and as resources on a page?

Answer (score 162):

**Access to Opaque Responses' Headers / Body**

The most straightforward limitation around opaque responses is that you cannot get meaningful information back from most of the [properties](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#response-class) of the `Response` class, like [`headers`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-response-headers), or call the various [methods](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#body) that make up the `Body` interface, like [`json()`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-body-json) or [`text()`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-body-text). This is in keeping with the black-box nature of an opaque response.

**Using Opaque Responses as Resources on a Page**

Opaque responses can be used as a resource on a web page whenever the browser allows for a non-CORS cross-origin resource to be used. Here's a subset of elements for which non-CORS cross-origin resources, and therefor opaque responses, are valid, adapted from the [Mozilla Developer Network documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_network_access):

- `<script>`
- `<link rel="stylesheet">`
- `<img>`, `<video>`, and `<audio>`
- `<object>` and `<embed>`
- `<iframe>`

A notable use case for which opaque responses are **not** valid is for [font resources](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#same-origin-restriction).

In general, to determine whether you can use an opaque response as a particular type of resource on a page, check the relevant specification. For example, the [HTML specification explains](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-crossorigin) that non-CORS cross-origin (i.e. opaque) responses can be used for `<script>` elements, though with some limitations to prevent leaking error information.

**Opaque Responses & the Cache Storage API**

One "gotcha" that developer [might run into](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/commit/e2a6d18647b97707c7a571163eef7838f82ca611#commitcomment-18733449) with opaque responses involves using them with the [Cache Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage). Two pieces of background information are relevant:

- The [`status`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-response-status) property of an opaque response is [always set to `0`](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/299), regardless of whether the original request succeeded or failed.
- The Cache Storage API's [`add()`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/index.html#cache-add)/[`addAll()`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/index.html#cache-addAll) methods will both reject if the responses resulting from any of the requests have a status code that isn't in the [2XX range](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ok-status).

From those two points, it follows that if the request performed as part of the `add()`/`addAll()` call results in an opaque response, it will fail to be added to the cache.

You can work around this by explicitly performing a `fetch()` and then calling the [`put()`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/index.html#cache-put) method with the opaque response. By doing so, you're effectively opting-in to the risk that the response you're caching might have been an error returned by your server.

```js
const request = new Request('https://third-party-no-cors.com/', {
  mode: 'no-cors',
});

// Assume `cache` is an open instance of the Cache class.
fetch(request).then(response => cache.put(request, response));
```

**Opaque Responses & the navigator.storage API**

In order to avoid leakage of cross-domain information, there's significant padding added to the size of an opaque response used for calculating storage quota limits (i.e. whether a `QuotaExceeded` exception is thrown) and reported by the [`navigator.storage` API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/estimating-available-storage-space).

The details of this padding vary from browser to browser, but for Google Chrome, this means that the *minimum* size that any single cached opaque response contributes to the overall storage usage is [approximately 7 megabytes](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=796060#c17). You should keep this in mind when determining how many opaque responses you want to cache, since you could easily exceeded storage quota limitations much sooner than you'd otherwise expect based on the actual size of the opaque resources.

Comment: Great answer! So how can we deal with the fonts? [DevTools screenshot](http://take.ms/6s3vU)

Comment: Got the answer at [googlechrome.github.io](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/selective-caching/service-worker.js), I forgot to clone the request.

Comment: Does the 7 MB storage padding constitute an actual storage usage, or is it just the fake value returned by the API?

Comment: It does not actually take up that amount of space on a device's physical storage. It's just the value that contributes to the quota calculations.

Comment: Your answer is even mentioned in the Workbox guide here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/handle-third-party-requests

Comment: True, but I did write that Workbox guide :-)

Comment: Does that make using an image CDN in conjunction with this kind of cache a bad design? (Wasting allocated space) Is it possible to cache a file retrieved from our main domain and expose it with the CDN link (key)? For example can I have a network request go to `cdn.x.com/test.jpg` and cache requests go to the main domain `www.x.com/test.jpg`.

Comment: I found a trickery around this problem, I have no idea if that's a decent solution but I basically make my service worker pretend it is the CDN. I add domain relative URLs in cache (eg., `/test.jpg` then for each fetch request to `cdn.x.com/test.jpg` I modify the URL with the origin domain (the URL becomes `www.x.com/test.jpg`), I use something like this: `const cacheUrl = (url.hostname == 'cdn.x.com')? new URL(event.target.location.origin + url.pathname): url;`. I then request the cache with this new url `caches.match(cacheUrl)`, that seems to work fine. Any though on this approach?

Comment: @cglacet.  I tried that, but the files still appear as "opaque" and a large size is still reported to the storage API.

Comment: *“Opaque responses can be used as a resource on a web page whenever the browser allows for a non-CORS cross-origin resource to be used.”* – How do I use the response in any of these elements? For example, `HTMLObjectElement.data` requires an URL, but can I convert an opaque response into an URL?

Comment: If an opaque response is like a black-box, then what if it's a broken response? e.g., if we've cached it, then later when it's used, it will be a broken response used...?

Comment: Took me a while to understand but I think that with `<script>` you didn't mean the code inside, but the `src` attribute, hence this is why you can maybe get js scripts from almost anywhere ?