# Application Cache Storage items have empty response?

Tags: caching, webpack, browser-cache, application-cache, sw-precache

I'm getting my preactjs website set up with service worker.

Using the [Sw-precache-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache)

I'm just looking at the cache items it stores in the Cache Storage, and the entries I expected are all there but they have an empty response.

I checked some other websites with service workers and noticed their entries have a response of "OK".

Just wondering what is the trigger to make a cache response say "OK" rather than blank.

[image]

Another example I found where some return OK and others Blank

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Response" column in Chrome's cache storage viewer is meant to reflect the value of the `statusText` field of the associated `Response` object. The traditional [status line](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1) for a successful response is '200 OK', so 'OK' is the `statusText` portion of that. You can see this in action by storing a `Response` with a different `statusText`, e.g.:

[image]

Sometimes when there is no 'OK' listed, it's because the `Response` is [opaque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109789/what-limitations-apply-to-opaque-responses), and the `statusText` isn't accessible. That's the case for those font resources in your second screenshot.

That being said, I have seen situations in which responses that are not opaque, like those `sw-precache`-managed entries in your first screenshot, don't have the `statusText` reflected properly. It might be in those situations that your web server is just responding with '200' status line rather than '200 OK', which would translate to a `status` of `200` and a `statusText` of `''`. That's a perfectly valid thing for a web server to use for a status line, and as long as the entries are being used successfully, I don't think you need to worry about it.