# ServiceWorker fails to fetch external resource without reason

Tags: javascript, caching, request, service-worker, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch and cache some external resources/websites using a service worker.

My code in `service-worker.js` is the following:

```
'use strict';

var static_urls = [
    'https://quiqqer.local/test?app=1',
    'https://quiqqer.local/calendar?app=1'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function (event)
{
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open('ionic-cache').then(function(cache) {
            cache.addAll(static_urls.map(function (urlToPrefetch)
            {
                console.log(urlToPrefetch);
                return new Request(urlToPrefetch, {mode: 'no-cors'});
            })).catch(function(error) {
                console.error(error);
            }).then(function() {
                console.log('All fetched and cached');
            });
        })
    );
});
```

Which creates this output:

```
service-worker.js: https://quiqqer.local/test?app=1
service-worker.js: https://quiqqer.local/calendar?app=1
service-worker.js: TypeError: failed to fetch
service-worker.js: All fetched and cached 
(index): service worker installed
```

What is the reason for the failing fetch?

My site https://quiqqer.local has set the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to '`*`'

Maybe it's my self-signed certificate for my site?

I added an exception for this certificate, so if I open the site Chrome shows that the site isn't secure next to the URL bar but the content is still displayed.

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab? There's more to supporting [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) than just that one header.

Comment: Separately: Remember that if you use `catch` and don't throw an error inside your `catch` handler or return a promise that is/will be rejected, you're converting a rejection into a resolution (which is why you see "All fetched and cached" when they aren't, in fact, all fetched and cached).

Comment: Without the catch it looks like this:

Comment: service-worker.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: In the Network tab I see the two requests but the status is "(canceled)"

Comment: Re the `catch`: Yes, exactly, because the fetch failed. You'd want that `catch` at the **end** of the chain, not in the middle, so it's not converting a rejection into a resolution.

Comment: Re (cancelled): So have you researched the causes of seeing (cancelled) requests in the Network tab?

Comment: I just had a look at chrome://net-internals/#events to see some more details about the request and there I found "net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)" which according to the Chromium source code means: "An operation was aborted (due to user action)".

Answer (score 1):

Since you're explicitly setting `{mode: 'no-cors'}`, you're going to get back an [opaque `Response`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109789/what-limitations-apply-to-opaque-responses)—one that always has a response code of `0`.

`cache.add()` will [throw a `TypeError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/add#Exceptions) if the `Response` that you're attempting to add to the cache has a code outside of the `2xx` range.

Because you have CORS enabled on your server, via the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, you can just make a request with its `mode` set to `'cors'`. `'cors'` `mode` is the default for cross-origin URLs, so

```
cache.addAll(static_urls)
  .then(...)
  .catch(...);
```

should give you the behavior that you want.

**If** you were making a request against a server that didn't support CORS, and you wanted to cache it, then you'd have to explicitly set `{mode: 'no-cors'}` and use a combination of `fetch()` + `cache.put()` to add the opaque response the cache. (And you'd have to assume the risk that the opaque response isn't a 4xx or 5xx error, since there's no way of knowing.) **But**, you don't have to worry about that because your server does support CORS.