# Can a service worker fetch outside its domain?

Tags: service-worker, fetch-api

I'm using a service worker mainly for push notifications. When receiving a message event, is it possible to fetch a URL outside the service worker's domain (for storing subscription data, for instance)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a service worker fetch and cache cross-origin assets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54619653/can-a-service-worker-fetch-and-cache-cross-origin-assets)

Comment: Yes. See the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54659324/441757 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/44183524/441757