# Using workbox runtime caching, requests are not showing on cache storage on chrome

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I am using workbox runtime caching to cache external calls (materialize.css is one of those). In my network tab it shows that the request is coming from serviceWorker (looks fine):

[image]

But on cache storage my runtime cache looks empty:

[image]

You can see my service worker on chromes's application tab, and this is the website: https://quack.surge.sh/

Service worker code:

```
const workboxSW = new self.WorkboxSW();
workboxSW.precache(fileManifest);
workboxSW.router.registerNavigationRoute("/index.html");workboxSW.router.registerRoute(/^https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dc3dnmmpx\/image\/upload\/.*/, workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst({}), 'GET');
workboxSW.router.registerRoute('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css', workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst({}), 'GET');
workboxSW.router.registerRoute('https://res.cloudinary.com/dc3dnmmpx/image/upload/(.*)', workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst({}), 'GET');
```

Is this the expected behaviour? I'm pretty new to service workers and I am not sure what is the correct result.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The underlying issue is that those are [opaque responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109789/what-limitations-apply-to-opaque-responses/39109790#39109790), and by default, they won't be used with a `cacheFirst` strategy.

There's some background at https://workboxjs.org/how_tos/cdn-caching.html

There's logging in Workbox to help debug this sort of thing, but as it's noisy, it's not enabled by default in the production build. Either switching your `importScripts()` to use the development build (e.g. `importScripts('https://unpkg.com/workbox-sw@2.0.3/build/importScripts/workbox-sw.dev.v2.0.3.js')`, or going in to DevTools and explicitly setting `workbox.LOG_LEVEL = 'debug'` would give you a log message like the following:

[image: DevTools log]

You have a few options for getting things working as you expect:

- Change to `workboxSW.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate()`, which supports opaque response by default.
- Tell the `cacheFirst` strategy that you're okay with it using opaque responses: `workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst({cacheableResponse: {statuses: [0, 200]}})`
- Because your third-party CDNs all seem to support CORS, you could opt-in to CORS mode for your CSS and image requests via the [`crossorigin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-crossorigin) attribute, and the responses will no longer be opaque: `<img src='https://cors.example.com/path/to/image.jpg' crossorigin='anonymous'>` or `<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cors.example.com/path/to/styles.css' crossorigin='anonymous'>`

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I didn't know about opaque responses. Workbox documentation is very short in my opinion, so it is hard to debug these kind of issues. Thanks again.

Comment: be careful to run into quota problems, when allowing the opaque (http 0) respones to be cached

Comment: Thanks, the background link seems to have been moved to https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/handle-third-party-requests