# Cache storage is empty when using workbox with CDN

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I am using workbox to cache my app shell. The network tab shows that the requests are coming from serviceWorker, and assets are definitely cached as they are retrieved in a snap, even on offline mode:

[image: network tab]

However, the cache storage tab is always empty:

[image: Cache storage empty]

I have attempted to request the same assets via console:

```
const request = new Request('https://d198jdpljt0zhj.cloudfront.net/assets/bundles/vendor-0332fe450952d0d66900.js', {mode: 'no-cors'});
fetch(request).then(response => console.log(response));
```

And voila, asset is shown:

[image: cache added]

I'm afraid I'm missing something fundamental.

By the way, cache storage is shown correctly in my local environment, so I suspect this is an issue with assets coming from CDN.

Comment: maybe you already know, but you can right click the cache and refresh it

Comment: Yeap :) No difference!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is almost certainly because your CDN doesn't support CORS, and only some strategies cache [opaque responses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39109790/385997) by default.

You can override this with

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('^https://third-party.example.com/assets/'), 
  workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'assets-cache',
    cacheableResponse: {
      statuses: [0, 200], // Make sure 0 is included in this list.
    }
  })
);
```

There is [logging about this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/master/packages/workbox-cacheable-response/src/lib/cacheable-response.js#L103) in v2 of Workbox, but only if you specifically have it enabled.

In the upcoming v3 release, we're [much more aggressive](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/pull/1035/files) about logging this, as it is a frequent source of frustration.

This [draft](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CyWBwJnIVOtTfSAvzgWT_wwYvcGBzPw0jTRBx5R22DQ/edit#heading=h.dxqzzrtjdji) of a section of the Workbox v3 docs goes into more detail.

Comment: Hi Jeff, mystery (partly) solved. I had a piece of code that was deleting the cache on the activation event of the service worker, which explains the empty cache tab and the re-appearance on the fetch event. By removing that code, it works as expected. What still puzzles me though is that assets were available on offline mode.

Comment: I am marking the response as accepted as I had several opaque responses which were made visible. Definitely a good decision to log them more aggressively on v3.