# Identify Origin/Source of FetchEvent Request

Tags: service-worker, fetch-api, service-worker-events

Is there any way for a ServiceWorker to identify the source or origin of a no-cors/opaque `FetchEvent.Request`? Or can we explicitly pass identifying information/data from the HTML to the `ServiceWorker` that could be used to identify origins of `FetchEvents`?. I hacked together a solution using query string parameters, but I'm looking for something more native or elegant than this:

**HTML**

```
<img id="img1" src="image.jpg?imgId=img1" />
<img id="img2" src="image.jpg?imgId=img2" />
```

**Service Worker**

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  const url = new URL(event.request.url);
  if(url.pathname.endsWith('/image.jpg')) {
    // get Element ID that initated the FetchEvent
    const imgId = url.searchParams.get('imgId');

    // Notify document that the fetch started
    clients.get(event.clientId)
    .then(client => client.postMessage({imgId}));
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, from the point of view of the service worker's `fetch` handler, the fact that the request has a `mode` of `'no-cors'` shouldn't change anything. [Opaque **responses**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109789/what-limitations-apply-to-opaque-responses) are a thing in order to prevent information leakage from third-party servers, but when you're talking about a **request** that originated from your own page being intercepted by your own service worker, there isn't the same concern about information leakage.

So, in general, the question is whether there's a way to get the browser to add in extra identifying information to the requests it implicitly creates for any subresource referenced in your DOM. Taking a look at the fields exposed in the [`Request` object](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#request), there really isn't anything other than `url` that you have control over and could potentially set to something useful for identifying your outgoing requests. (You won't be able to control the `headers` for the implicitly created requests used for subresources referenced in your DOM.)

If you wanted to prevent the "noise" of using parameters to add in the identifying information to the `url`, you should be able to get away with using hash fragments, like

```
<img id="img1" src="image.jpg#img1">
<img id="img2" src="image.jpg#img2">
```

The [service worker specification states](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/854) that the hash fragment should be included in the `request.url` that's passed in to your `fetch` handler, so you can read it from there, but it won't actually be sent to the remote server.

(One of the things that you *can* get is the [`destination`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-destination) of a `Request` object, if you wanted to distinguish between requests which will be used for images, fonts, scripts, etc. But that won't allow you to identify which specific `<img>` was responsible for a given image request.)

Comment: Brilliant idea to use fragments without using passing to server.

Comment: FYI: A Firefox 59 bug was filed for Service Workers using hash fragments: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1443850