# How to make workbox cache cross origin responses?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, workbox

According to [workbox doc](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing), cross domain request should be configured  to ensure that regular expression matches the beginning of the URL. However, it doesn't work.

The service worker code is like below.

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.0.0/workbox-sw.js');

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  /.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)/,
  workbox.strategies.cacheFirst()
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('^https://a248.e.akamai.net/.*'),
  workbox.strategies.cacheFirst()
);
```

In the page, responses from same origin resources are cached, but responses from `https://a248.e.akami.net` is not.

Anything wrong with my config? or is this a workbox 3.0.0 bug?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you have CORS enabled on your `https://a248.e.akami.net` server? If not, you'll be getting back [opaque responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109789/what-limitations-apply-to-opaque-responses/39109790#39109790), and by default, those will not be cached when using a `cacheFirst` strategy.

There's a [guide for handling third-party requests](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/handle-third-party-requests#force_caching_of_opaque_responses) with a recipe you could use if you want to opt-in to caching those responses when using a `cacheFirst` strategy:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('^https://a248.e.akamai.net/.*'),
  workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
    plugins: [
      new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({
        statuses: [0, 200]
      })
    ]
  }),
);
```

You should also see a new warning logged in the JavaScript console when using Workbox v3 in localhost when this situation arises, explaining what's going on.

Comment: Looks like `networkFirst` and `staleWhileRevalidate` strategies (documentation version 6.0.2) state that they cache opaque (that's how the documentation calls responses which don't support CORS) responses as well, so we can use those too?

Comment: "By default, this strategy will cache responses with a 200 status code as well as opaque responses. Opaque responses are cross-origin requests where the response doesn't support CORS." https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate

Comment: Yes, you could use those without having to add in the `CacheableResponsePlugin`.