# vue-cli + workbox not caching content

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, workbox

I am using vue-cli v3.0.0.beta10 + the default integrated workbox, I added the following configuration in my `vue.config.js` file (located in my root folder):

```
pwa: {
        //pwa configs... 

        workboxOptions: {
        // ...other Workbox options...
        runtimeCaching: [ {
           urlPattern: new RegExp('/.*(?:googleapis)\.com.*$/'),
           handler: 'staleWhileRevalidate',
        }]
       }
}
```

I would expect my serviceworker to cache all json responses from my google api but instead nothing happens. I can't even see the Cache Storage in the developer toolbox under the "Application" tab.
What am I missing? Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RegExp is not correct. The leading and trailing `/` should not be there since you are also wrapping the pattern in a string.

You can test the RegExp like this:

```
new RegExp('/.*(?:googleapis)\.com\/.*$/').exec('https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists')
=> null
```

Try removing the leading and trailing `/`:

```
new RegExp('.*(?:googleapis)\.com\/.*$').exec('https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists')
=> ["https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists", index: 0, input: "https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists", groups: undefined]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works but it only caches images from my google backend, do you know why it does not do the same with a list of json objects that I retrieve from the same backend service?

Comment: For anyone reading this thread, please notice that I am using a "staleWhileRevalidate" caching strategy. If you use "cacheFirst" you may want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49295757/how-to-make-workbox-cache-cross-origin-responses?rq=1) and understand opaque responses

Answer (score 1):

Do you use [workbox-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workbox-webpack-plugin)?

```
const workboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin')

// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new workboxPlugin({
        ...
        runtimeCaching: [ {
           urlPattern: new RegExp('/.*(?:googleapis)\.com.*$/'),
           handler: 'staleWhileRevalidate',
        }]
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: workbox-webpack-plugin is included by default in vue-cli3.0.0-beta.10