# Service Worker - TypeError: Request failed

Tags: typeerror, fetch-api, service-worker

I used service worker to cache the resource from the other domain. I get this error "TypeError: Request failed             serivce-worker.js:12" I don't know why this error is occurring.

**service-worker.js**

```js
var cacheNames=['v1'];
var urlsToPrefetch=['file from other domain'];

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheNames).then(function(cache) {
            console.log('Service Worker: Caching Files');
            cache.addAll(urlsToPrefetch.map(function (urlToPrefetch) {
                console.log(urlToPrefetch);
                return  new Request(urlToPrefetch, {mode: 'no-cors'});
            })).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
            });
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    console.log('Service Worker: Fetching');
    event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
        return fetch(event.request);
      }
    )
  );
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a side-effect of dealing with opaque responses (those fetched with `mode: 'no-cors'`). Here's an excerpt from [this longer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39109790/385997):

One "gotcha" that developer [might run into](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/commit/e2a6d18647b97707c7a571163eef7838f82ca611#commitcomment-18733449) with opaque responses involves using them with the [Cache Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage). Two pieces of background information are relevant:

- The [`status`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-response-status) property of an opaque response is [always set to `0`](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/299), regardless of whether the original request succeeded or failed.
- The Cache Storage API's [`add()`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/index.html#cache-add)/[`addAll()`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/index.html#cache-addAll) methods will both reject if the responses resulting from any of the requests have a status code that isn't in the [2XX range](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ok-status).

From those two points, it follows that if the request performed as part of the `add()`/`addAll()` call results in an opaque response, it will fail to be added to the cache.

You can work around this by explicitly performing a `fetch()` and then calling the [`put()`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/index.html#cache-put) method with the opaque response. By doing so, you're effectively opting-in to the risk that the response you're caching might have been an error returned by your server.

```
const request = new Request('https://third-party-no-cors.com/', {mode: 'no-cors'});
// Assume `cache` is an open instance of the Cache class.
fetch(request).then(response => cache.put(request, response));
```