# How to cache response from google drive API in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, caching, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client, workbox

I want to reproduce music files from google drive on a web page. I have the link for each file but the response cache headers for the calls are 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate" so it will never be saved on the browser cache. Is there any way to add cache to google drive files requests?

The problem:

When you use the drive link for a music file (mp3)  https://drive.google.com/a/pucp.pe/uc?id=1kYYS9FZ9Vxif5WJM9ZQcY4SR35NMgoIE&export=download the GET API call receives a 302 code which generates a redirect to another URL, in this case, to 'https://doc-0o-28-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/bgp95l3eabkkpccn0qi0qopvc4e7d4mq/us95e8ush1v4b7vvijq1vj1d7ru4rlpo/1556330400000/01732506421897009934/01732506421897009934/1kYYS9FZ9Vxif5WJM9ZQcY4SR35NMgoIE?h=14771753379018855219&e=download'. Each of these calls has `no-cache` in headers.

1. I tried using workbox (cache API) but I don't find a way to cache redirects, probably I need to cache both calls (the first GET and the redirect). However, if I use the redirected URL the caching works, but I don't have access to that URL until the first call is made.
2. I tried to use a proxy server from a NodeJS server

```
app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    try {
      https.get(
        URL,
        function(response) {
          res.writeHead(response.statusCode, {...response.headers, 
            "Cache-Control": "public, max-age=120",
            "Expires": new Date(Date.now() + 120000).toUTCString() })

          response.pipe(res);
        }
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
```

I tried using the first URL with no luck.
I tried using the redirect URL but I get a "Status Code: 302 Found"

One solution could be to download the file and serve it directly from my server but I will be missing the point of using the drive storage. I really want to use google drive storage and not duplicate all files on my server.

Is there a recommended way to do the caching for this case? maybe there is some google drive configuration that I'm missing. Or do you know another approach I could take in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cache redirected responses using Workbox (and the Cache Storage API in general). HTTP 30x redirects are followed automatically [by default](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-redirect-mode), and you should only have to route the original, non-redirected URL.

Here's a live example of a Glitch project that uses Workbox to cache that MP3 file: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/horn-sausage?path=sw.js:9:0

The relevant snippet of code, that also accounts for the fact that there is no CORS used when serving the files (so you'll get back an [opaque response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109789/what-limitations-apply-to-opaque-responses) with a status of `0`) is:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('https://drive.google.com/'),
  new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
    plugins: [
      new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({statuses: [0, 200]})
    ],
  })
);
```