# How to reduce PWA website space usage? PWA taking up huge space

Tags: web, progressive-web-apps

I recently deployed my website (https://www.travelengine.co/) and started using PWA to enhance the experience. The PWA works good and is able to cache offline articles as well. However, the issue I am facing is that the **site usage has become huge**. It happens on my chrome android as well as chrome desktop. Even after clearing cache, the usage spikes close to 800MB within just 2 refreshes.

Please help. How should I fix that? I am attaching the screenshots.

PWA Location: https://www.travelengine.co/service-worker.js

[image: chrome site usage]

Comment: Without actual insight into your code and what you are doing this question is neigh impossible to answer. Spend some time looking into your code and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Are you caching files from somewhere other than your own domain? When reporting the size of resources that were fetched with CORS, Chrome obfuscates the file size for security reasons, and reports each file as ~7meg each.

I tried to visit https://www.travelengine.co/, and it looks like the service worker is failing, so I can't easily debug into it.

Comment: There's more info about the quota padding of opaque responses at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39109790/385997

Comment: @PeteLe: Thanks for your help. Indeed, I am caching files from other sources as well. That might be the case. It might be the case that chrome reports ~7MB each.
Also, thanks for visiting and checking the sw. I guess the sw isn't failing, its another bit of code that keeps sending 'uncaught error'.