# How to cache images from an API response

Tags: caching, service-worker, workbox

I am receiving images URLs from an API response and I want to cache each of those images. I tried just using cache.addAll but it does not work because the images are an opaque response. I am considering fetching each image using `fetch` and having the routes cache them but I am not sure as to whether this would be the best way. Are there any other better alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some guidance in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109789/what-limitations-apply-to-opaque-responses#:%7E:text=Opaque%20Responses%20%26%20the%20Cache%20Storage%20API) that explains how to cache opaque responses; the gist of it is:

```
const request = new Request('https://third-party-no-cors.com/', {
  mode: 'no-cors',
});

// Assume `cache` is an open instance of the Cache class.
fetch(request).then(response => cache.put(request, response));
```

The caveat is that your code has no way of knowing whether you're caching a valid response, or a HTTP 404 or some other error.

Comment: Where should I do this? Inside my service worker or inside my React component, or some other place?

Comment: Either. It's up to you. The Cache Storage API and Fetch are both available in a SW or web page.