# unable to cache CORS assets like css, js and image using service worker

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I am stuck with my first PWA project.
few of my assets are in the same domain and a few others came from a subdomain.
my domain is adc.com and the assets server is asset.abc.com
I need to cache all js, CSS, and images that belong to both servers.
using simple javascript and Html

Comment: Does the info at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109789/what-limitations-apply-to-opaque-responses help?

Comment: +1 Jeff's comment.
If you have header control over the server in your subdomain I would suggest adding [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) and save yourself the headache of having to deal with opaque responses within a Service Worker (also eliminating the possibility to cache a 404 response and anything else apart from status 200).