# Vue PWA: Check if response was from cache and how old it is

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I'm using vue-pwa for my site and am currently using the NetworkFirst strategy for an API that I call inside my site. I now want to somehow detect if the response I received from the API was cached by the service worker (in which case I want to know how old that cached response is) or if the request was fetched normally. The goal is to display a warning if the user is viewing potentially out of date content (the response was loaded from cache and is older than a few hours)

Here's my current `sw.js`

```js
self.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
  if (!e.data) {
    return
  }

  switch (e.data) {
    case 'skipWaiting':
      self.skipWaiting()
      break
    default:
      break
  }
})

workbox.core.clientsClaim()

self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || [])
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(/^https:\/\/some.api.here.com\//, new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst(), 'GET');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it's important to have the correct [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) in your API (if it lives on an origin different than the website's). This is necessary in order to get the *full* response back instead of [opaque responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109789/what-limitations-apply-to-opaque-responses/39109790#39109790).

Now for getting the time the item was cached, you have to access the [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object from within the Cache.

> Each resource cached by Workbox can be found as a *key* within a [Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) as a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object.

After finding the Response object for the specific resource you are looking for, get the [Date HTTP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Field_names:%7E:text=Date) from the Response:

```
let cacheNames = await caches.keys()
let cachesStorage = {}
let promises = cacheNames.map(async cacheName => {
    const cache = await caches.open(cacheName)
    const cachedResources = await cache.keys()

    for (const request of cachedResources) {
        const response = await cache.match(request)
        console.log(response.headers.get('Date'))
        // CHECK DATE HERE AND COMPARE WITH CURRENT DATE
    }
    
    return cacheName
})
await Promise.all(promises)
```