# Accessing in Chrome POST response body from Cloudflare Worker

Tags: javascript, post, postman, fetch-api, chrome-debugging

I am trying to read a response from a Cloudflare Worker API, I have not set anything sepcial about it and in Postman the request works as expected. I am guessing I am missing some header but I am not sure  which one or even if that is the reason reading the reponses body is not working in browser.

This is how I fetch the data:

```
    const url = `${process.env.SOME_URL}/v1/method?token=${TOKEN}`
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
   

    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        redirect: 'follow',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers
        // referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
    };

    return fetch(url, requestOptions)
        .then(async (response) => {
            // no body to be parsed
            return response.json()
        } )
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Looking forward to your answers, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is due to the `no-cors` config of the `fetch-api`.
For more details read about opaque  requests here:

[What limitations apply to opaque responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109789/what-limitations-apply-to-opaque-responses/39109790#39109790)