# Bad Request (400) When Trying to Authenticate Harvest API in React

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, cors, fetch-api, harvest

So I'm building a status board for our internal use as developers here in the office. It will show number of commits, hours tracked, etc.

I am following this [model](http://help.getharvest.com/api/authentication/authentication/server-side-apps/) for authenticating. After a user logs in with harvest it redirects them back to the app with the code param as a query string, I'm then taking that query string and passing it to a state to then do a fetch to get the access token (so that I can later pull API data).

What happens, is the login is successful but when you are redirected back to the app the fetch throws a Bad Request (400) error. I have tested in Postman and can get the correct response so I'm not sure what the issue is...

Here is some of the JS from the Main component that sets the states if there is a code param:

```
harvestState() {

// grab URL params
let urlParams = queryString.parse(location.search);
console.log(urlParams);
console.log(urlParams.code);

// set the state based on the paramater passed back
urlParams.code ? (
  this.setState({
    harvestcode: urlParams.code
  })
) : (
  this.setState({
    harvestcode: 'none'
  })
);
}

componentWillMount(){
  this.harvestState();
}
```

And here is the fetch function in my Harvest component:

```
  getHarvest(){
    const clientSecret = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
    // Set Harvest Headers
   const harvestHeaders = {
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     },
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    body: {
      'code': this.props.code,
      'client_id': this.props.clientid,
      'client_secret': clientSecret,
      'redirect_uri': 'http://dash.mycompany.me',
      'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
    }
   };

   fetch('https://mycompany.harvestapp.com/oauth2/token', harvestHeaders)
   .then( response => response.json() )
   .then( token => {

     console.log(token);

   } )
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    if( this.props.code !== 'none' ){
      this.getHarvest();
    }
  }
```

Is there something here that I am doing wrong? Why does it always return a bad request? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I notice `mode: 'no-cors'`, so the client Web app making the requests is running on the same origin (scheme+domain+port) as the server the requests are sent to?

Comment: @sideshowbarker no they are on separate servers, but without using it I get a console log about turning it on to get a response...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one issue you have is that when you use `mode: 'no-cors'` you’re telling the browser to handle the response as an [opaque response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292537/what-is-an-opaque-request-and-what-it-serves-for), which means that you’re telling the browser to not make any properties of the response object accessible from JavaScript.

So if you make a `mode: 'no-cors'` request, `response => response.json()` is going to fail.

The only purpose for `no-cors` in practice is in combination with Service Workers when you’re just caching resources (e.g., images) from responses, without need to get  properties of the responses.

Anyway, given that the client Web app making the requests in your deployment is running from a different origin than the server the requests are sent to, browsers are going to block the requests unless the server responds with the necessary CORS headers—`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, for a start. For an explanation, see the MDN article [HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

That is, browsers block cross-origin requests made from JavaScript unless the server the requests are sent to opts-in to allowing those, with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, etc., response headers. The reason Postman doesn’t block such requests is that Postman is not an arbitrary Web app running at some specific origin on the Web but is instead a browser plugin that you’ve intentionally installed. So it’s not bound the cross-origin restrictions browser enforce for Web apps.

Comment: Yeah I think that I need to make the request with CURL instead of with fetch. Thanks!