# Text response is empty when using fetch

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

The following code:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/root/1487171054127/k_query_bearer_token', {
        mode: 'no-cors', credentials: 'include'
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.text();
        })
        .then(function (text) {
            console.log('Request successful', text.length);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            log('Request failed', error)
        });
```

is outputting:

```
Request successful 0
```

If I use curl:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/root/1487171054127/k_query_bearer_token' \
  -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=CviS9IK8pcsqADdP-m0MRXX_AvUqfzjJPwk1Yytf.ee16d0a01ad5'
```

I get a token in text form back (length != 0).

And if I output the response header via:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/root/1487171054127/k_query_bearer_token' 
  -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=CviS9IK8pcsqADdP-m0MRXX_AvUqfzjJPwk1Yytf.ee16d0a01ad5'
  --head
```

I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Server: JBoss-EAP/7
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 1730
Date: Wed, 15 Feb 2017 16:17:00 GMT
```

Why am I getting no text via fetch?

Comment: What is your expected response? response.text() will return a promise which will contain USVString: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Remove `mode: 'no-cors'`.

When you use `no-cors` mode, you’re explicitly specifying that you want an [“opaque response”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292537/what-is-an-opaque-request-and-what-it-serves-for).

Your script can’t access any properties of  an opaque response—instead essentially all you can do is cache it. `no-cors` mode is basically useful only when doing caching with Service Workers.

If the reason you have your script using `no-cors` mode is because cross-origin requests to the server otherwise won’t work, the right solution is either to update the server-side code to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header and other CORS headers—if you have access to the server do to that—or else, use a proxy like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/.

Comment: You're a legend. I thought it was because of the client side code since the server side was giving a response.. Nope!