# How do I fix CORS issue in Fetch API

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

I'm building a front-end only basic Weather App using reactjs. For API requests I'm using Fetch API.
In my app, I'm getting the current location from a [simple API](http://ip-api.com/json) I found
and it gives the location as a JSON object. But when I request it through Fetch API, I'm getting this error.

> Failed to load http://ip-api.com/json: Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

So I searched through and found multiple solutions to fix this.

1. Enabling CORS in Chrome solves the error but when I deploy the app on heroku, how can I access it through a mobile device without running into the same CORS issue.
2. I found an [proxy API](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/) which enables the CORS requests. But as this is a location request, this gives me the location of the proxy server. So it's not a solution.
3. I've gone through this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727306/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-access-contr) and added the headers to the header in my http request but it doesn't solve the problem. (Still it gives the same error).

So how can I solve the issue permanently ? What's the best solution I can use to solve the CORS issue for http requests in Fetch API ?

Comment: that server is configured to disallow you from fetching it from a browser (CORS). You can get it all day with cURL. If you can't get them to add the CORS header on their Web server, rethink your idea.

Comment: Read the error message closely... you appear to be setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as a **request** header. This is a **response** header only, it must come from the server and has no place in your request. This would have been trivially easy to point out if you included _any_ code in your question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*To the countless future visitors*:

If my original answer doesn't help you, you may have been looking for:

- [Trying to use fetch and pass in mode: no-cors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43262121/86967)
- [What is an opaque response, and what purpose does it serve?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36292537/86967)

---

*Regarding the issue faced by the OP...*

That API appears to be permissive, responding with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`

I haven't figured out what is causing your problem, but I don't think it is simply the [fetch API](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fetch-api/info).

This worked fine for me in both Firefox and Chrome...

```
fetch('http://ip-api.com/json')
   .then( response => response.json() )
   .then( data => console.log(data) )
```

Comment: I've added the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` in Fetch API request. But it don't solve the problem. It works only when I enable the CORS in the browser using a plugin.

Comment: I seem to be missing something, but *you* should not be adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` to your request -- the API server puts that in their response.  Which they do, according to my test.

Comment: After reading about adding headers and many things I've added headers in my request. And I replaced the whole fetch API request with what you mentioned and it works a charm. Thanks a lot

Comment: It worked for me with this args:

`fetch('http://ip-api.com/json', { method: "GET", mode: 'cors', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',}}).then(response => response.json())`

Thanks to Nafiu Lawal

Comment: From what I can tell, the default value for [Request.mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode) is `cors`.

Answer (score 6):

if you are making a `post`, `put` or `patch` request, you have to stringify your data with `body: JSON.stringify(data)`

```
fetch(URL, 
        {
            method: "POST", 
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        }
    ).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        ....
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        ....
        })
    });
```

Comment: how to do this with get request?

Comment: get requests do not include a `body` in the request object. That is why it is not mentioned above (you don't need it).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the proxy solution, but pass it the IP of the client instead of the proxy. Here is an example URL format for the API you specified, using the IP of WikiMedia:

http://ip-api.com/json/208.80.152.201

Comment: This works.

But hard-coding IP as this will be a problem when I log in from a different IP right ? 
So how can I get the client IP as the IP is in the response object. So how can I get the IP before send the request (to attach in the request as you've mentioned) ?

Comment: To make a proxy you need server side code (like PHP, ruby, etc). You would simply look at the IP of the incoming request, use that in the URL, get the response (in PHP still), take THAT response and then send it to the actual browser (so the browser is not the one making the request). That will bypass the CORS restrictions because the file is placed on your own domain, and CORS no longer applies.

Comment: You won't be able to do this in JS alone unless you use JSONP, it appears they support it: http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that.
btw, seems like it was a issue with headers in my request. Fixed it by replacing a simple code which the other guy has mentioned and it works like charm