# How to get fetch status code when it fails with "TypeError: Failed to fetch"?

Tags: javascript, fetch, http-status-code-403

I have the following code:

```js
    let response = null;
    try {
      response = await fetch(url, { method,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        }
      });
      console.log("Status", response?.status);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error", e);
      console.log("Response", response);
    }
```

My request fails with status code 403, but I cannot get this `403` from nowhere. The code above doesn't get to the line `console.log("Status", response?.status);`, instead it goes into `catch` section, where `response` is `undefined` and `e` is error with message `"TypeError: Failed to fetch"` and stacktrace, but without any further details about the response (actually, I looked for response status code).

[image: screenshot of failed fetch with 403 status code]

Does anybody have idea how do I get that status code (`403` in my example) when fetch fails into catch section?

Comment: that error can indicate a CORS error - a 403 response status will not throw an error by itself, so something else is going on

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48728173/how-do-i-fix-cors-issue-in-fetch-api for CORS issues

Comment: Thanks, but those answers are about CORS issues, telling how to resolve them. In my question I don't need to resolve it, I need to get the status code - is it 401, 403, or other one? I need to know and make further processing based on that status code. The problem is that I cannot get this number, even though I can clearly see it in Network tab. I also had CORS issue for another request, but in Network tab it was displayed as red "CORS", not red "403". So I wonder how to get that status code (403 or whatever it is) if response is undefined and error looks like doesn't contain it?

Comment: @MaxímG. What did the preflight request return?

Comment: The error is "Failed to fetch", presumably due to a CORS issue. This means the response is opaque to your JavaScript code. You cannot get the status because no response is visible to your code for security reasons.

Comment: A response object if attached to your `error` object only if it got a `response` from the server, and there you would find the status, like `404` if not found, `200+` if it's OK, `300+` if redirected, `500+` if internal server error, and `400+` and `403` for different errors caught by the server. But some errors come from Browsers RESTRICTIONS, like CORS, Failed Connection, Internet Connection, then your `error` object WILL NOT have `response`, but simply a `message` attribute. So I think it's safe to consider anything like that a `400+` status code by default, and check `error.message`.

Comment: @Phil, thank you for your comment. Pity that I cannot get it, but at least you provided me clear reason for that. If you can make it as an answer instead of comment, I will accept it as correct answer, because all the rest answers suggest me to process `response` or `error` - that I already tried all ways I could - it doesn't work. You explained the reason why it's impossible - I'll accept it.

Answer (score -2):

Try using `response.ok`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok

Using your example:

```
if (response.ok) {
    console.log("Status", response.status);
} else {
    console.log("Response is not OK, status:", response.status);
}
```

By using 'response.ok' you're checking for error codes 200-299

Comment: Thank you for this response. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve my task - to get actual status code (the number). Also, immediately after calling `await fetch...` it comes to catch - so any further lines (like checking response.ok) are being skipped, and response is undefined (so that response.ok would raise another error like trying to access property `ok` of undefined). But thanks for nice try, sorry to see it downvoted because someone might find it helpful even though it doesn't resolve my original question.