# Problem fetching API data using React/JSX

Tags: reactjs, api, jsx

I am working on a small React project and wanted to fetch the data from the Fortnite API. I have this as a function to fetch upcoming items,

```
  const fetchItems = async () =>{
    const data = await fetch('https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/upcoming/get/');
    console.log(data);
  }
```

But I'm getting this as output,

> Access to fetch at
>   'https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/upcoming/get/'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>
> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
>   https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/upcoming/get/
>   with MIME type application/json. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details. fetchItems @ Shop.js:12 (anonymous) @ Shop.js:8
>   commitHookEffectList @ react-dom.development.js:21864
>   commitPassiveHookEffects @ react-dom.development.js:21897 callCallback
>   @ react-dom.development.js:363 invokeGuardedCallbackDev @
>   react-dom.development.js:412 invokeGuardedCallback @
>   react-dom.development.js:465 flushPassiveEffectsImpl @
>   react-dom.development.js:25316 unstable_runWithPriority @
>   scheduler.development.js:818 runWithPriority$2 @
>   react-dom.development.js:12259 flushPassiveEffects @
>   react-dom.development.js:25283 (anonymous) @
>   react-dom.development.js:25162 workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:762
>   flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:717 performWorkUntilDeadline @
>   scheduler.development.js:212

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Add a middleware like nodejs and hit the api from node.

Comment: look into this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292537/what-is-an-opaque-response-and-what-purpose-does-it-serve)

Comment: @humanbean Thanks, the answer on the link resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chrome sad (https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768):

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) is an algorithm that can identify
>   and block dubious cross-origin resource loads in web browsers before
>   they reach the web page. CORB reduces the risk of leaking sensitive
>   data by keeping it further from cross-origin web pages.

The API https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/upcoming/get/ don't accept 
your origin http://localhost:3000.

To disable origin policy in Chrome please see this post: [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)