# Get a JSON response from ESP8266 using fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I've created a ESP8266 web server that should send a JSON object when it's requested by the client. The code of this server looks like this:

```
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.disconnect();
  delay(10);
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Successfully connected.");
  Serial.println("\nGot IP: ");  
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  if(MDNS.begin("esp8266")) {
    Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
  }
  server.on("/data", []() {
    server.send(200, "application/json", "{\"key\": \"value\"}");
  });
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop() { 
  server.handleClient();
  MDNS.update();
}
```

Then I am trying to request the data from my JS code using `fetch` function. But it throws this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at index.js:8
```

When I simply connect to the server's data from my browser it is correctly displayed the JSON object on the page. This is my code to do request:

```
fetch('http://192.168.1.135/data', {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Any more feedback required here?

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

Remove `mode: 'no-cors'` and add `server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` in the sketch.

**Fetch modes**

`mode: 'no-cors'` is intended for caching with Service Workers.

> JavaScript may not access any properties of the resulting Response

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode

Hence, you are telling the engine to convert "nothing" to JSON which in turn leads to "Unexpected end of input".

Alternative explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36303436/131929

Use this trimmed JavaScript snippet; it's straight from the book.

```
fetch('http://esp8266.local/data')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

To use this even across the [same-origin constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), which apply unless the snippet is embedded in a (HTML) resource served by esp8266.local, the server needs to send a [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) header.

```
server.on("/data", []() {
  Serial.println("Serving /data");
  server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  server.send(200, "application/json", "{\"key\": \"value\"}");
});
```

**Goodie**

`headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}` is pointless because `Content-Type` is [a *response* header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Standard_response_fields). If at all you will want to use the ['Accept' request header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Standard_request_fields).