# Not able to get response body after fetch javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch, httpresponse

I'm having this annoying problem while trying to make a web app for an SMS Eagle.
I am trying to send an API request to the SMS Eagle server, to then send the SMS, which is succesful, but the only problem is that I can't seem to be able to get the response body.

In Javascript when I look at the response body property, the value is 'null'. But when I look in the network tab, I see the value. Notice how there is also 'status: 0' and other values that seem weird.
[image: Empty response body]
[image: Non empty response body in network tab]

I have tried getting the value with response.json(), response.text(), response.blob() etc.. What am I doing wrong here? I have already tried multiple content-type headers too. This is my code:

```js
fetch(`http://x.x.x.x/http_api/send_sms?login=${login_g}&pass=${pass_g}&message=${encodeURIComponent(message)}&to=${number}`, { method: 'GET', mode: 'no-cors', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}})
                    .then(response => response.text())
                    .then(data => console.log(data));
```

These are the response headers from the server:
[image: Server response headers]

Kind regards,
Jasper

Comment: You've set the mode of the request to `no-cors` which means that the response will be Opaque (also seen in Response type) and hence you cannot read it from Javascript. You can read this answer for more details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292537/what-is-an-opaque-response-and-what-purpose-does-it-serve

Comment: If you run into CORS errors without the `mode: no-cors` you can check out [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Comment: Alright thanks for the help, will check them out and try!

Comment: If the server end generates a 400 error etc, then your `then` is not going to trigger, you might want to also use `catch`..