# Is there a flag to disable subresource integrity checking in chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, chromium, playwright, subresource-integrity

We're using [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) and sometimes [playwright](https://playwright.dev/) to run some integration tests. We mock some of the target page's script dependencies, which causes [subresource integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) hash mismatches.

> Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://localhost:3000/static/third-party/adobe-target/at-js/2.4.0-cname/at.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity '47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='. The resource has been blocked."

Is there a way to disable integrity hash checking via a flag or configuration property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. I believe the only way is to fix or remove the `integrity` attribute from the source that loads the script.

Looking at the chromium (or blink) source, [unless the `integrity` attribute is empty](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/renderer/core/fetch/fetch_manager.cc;l=462), the `FetchManager::Loader` will instantiate the [`SRIVerifier`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/renderer/core/fetch/fetch_manager.cc;l=160), whose constructor calls its [`OnStateChange`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/renderer/core/fetch/fetch_manager.cc;l=183) method, where for response types of `basic`, `cors`, `default` (leaving out [`opaque`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292537/what-is-an-opaque-response-and-what-purpose-does-it-serve) responses and errors), [`SubresourceIntegrity::CheckSubresourceIntegrity`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/renderer/platform/loader/subresource_integrity.cc;l=90) is called. [Unless the parsing of the `integrity` attribute fails](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/renderer/platform/loader/subresource_integrity.cc;l=105), [`SubresourceIntegrity::CheckSubresourceIntegrityImpl`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/renderer/platform/loader/subresource_integrity.cc;l=134) will either successfully verify one of the digests, or it will fail with the given error message. There is no configuration option checked along this path to override a failed check.

Answer (score 3):

I confirm that you can't do this in Chrome. The reason being that it's not implemented behind a runtime flag. A flag like this can technically be added but probably not worth it.

I'm sure you can work around this, e.g. load puppeteer with an extension that removes the integrity attribute, or remove the attribute from within puppeteer?