# Uncaught (in promise) Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

I want to fetch a Markdown API, find out the link here:https://www.markdownguide.org/api/v1/basic-syntax.json, but it doesn't work I had this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

```
import React, {useState } from 'react'

const Docs = () => {
    const[docs, setDocs]=useState([]);

    const fetchDocs= async()=>{
              const resp=await fetch("https://www.markdownguide.org/api/v1/basic-syntax.json", { mode: 'no-cors'});
                const data = await resp.json();
                  console.log(data);
                return setDocs(data);
    }
  
  return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={fetchDocs}>Docs</button>
    
    </div>
  )
}

export default Docs
```

When I check out the value of resp

```
const resp=await fetch("https://www.markdownguide.org/api/v1/basic-syntax.json", { mode: 'no-cors'});
              console.log(resp);
```

I got this:

> Response {type: 'opaque', url: '', redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}body: (...)bodyUsed: falseheaders: Headers {}ok: falseredirected: falsestatus: 0statusText: ""type: "opaque"url: ""[[Prototype]]: Response

Comment: `mode: 'no-cors'` in the request and `type: 'opaque'` in the response imply to me that the response body wouldn't be readable by the code in the browser.  Which would mean it also can't be de-serialized.  If you use `resp.text()` instead to just get the raw text of the response, what does it contain?

Comment: I've tried resp.text(), i got this output: Promise {<fulfilled>: ''}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Promise
catch
: 
ƒ catch()
constructor
: 
ƒ Promise()
finally
: 
ƒ finally()
then
: 
ƒ then()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)
: 
"Promise"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
[[PromiseState]]
: 
"fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]
: 
""

Comment: What you're showing is a `Promise`, not the result of that `Promise`.  In the code shown the call to `resp.json()` is awaited, did you not await the call to `resp.text()`?

Comment: I got nothing when i make               console.log(await resp.text());

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an opaque response, and what purpose does it serve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292537/what-is-an-opaque-response-and-what-purpose-does-it-serve)

Comment: You can't just fetch stuff from another website in browser, that could be an unreasonable burden on the other website. So if you don't own this, presume that you can't fetch it unless they provide an explicit API and entry point for you to use.